# What test should be applied in SPSS?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

I have categorical data of drug relapse among the rehabilitated clients of drugs user. Some cell values are less than 5 ie. zero. chi square test can not be applied here. what test must be applied from SPSS?

```
Economic          Relapsed?
 status
          Yes         No         Total
         n   %      n   %       n    %

Poor    23  88.46   3   11.54   26  100
Medium  71  95.95   3   4.05    74  100
Higher  4   100     0   0       4   100
```

Comment: It's not the observed counts that are relevant, but the expected. What hypothesis are you testing? How does this question arise?

Comment: @Glen_b *Can we do the chi square test while the cell contains the cell value less than 5. similarly other problems were arisen in my research defense program.but still answered.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Assumptions ... the rule of thumb about *expected* counts is more than 60 years old (Cochran 1952 discusses this rule, I think); many papers since have suggested the rule is stricter than necessary.

Comment: @Glen_b *H0 : there is no association  between family size and Drug relapse.H1 : there is association betn....                              I have tested these problem through chi square test previously but in my research defense program, few external had said that you can not do chi square test while cell value is less than 5.SPSS also says the same. but still not getting answer.

Comment: I've seen SPSS complain about expected count before. Can you show SPSS saying that there's a problem with the *observed* count?

Comment: Note that Cochran himself (he appears to be the originator of the rule of thumb) says the rule is arbitrary, and suggests a weaker rule (no more than 20% of the cells have expected values between one and five). However, you have one extremely low expected value so it's probably worth pursuing the suggestions in the answer by Michael M.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't trust the results of a classic chi-squared test, you can use (a) Monte-Carlo simulation (from tables with identical marginal distributions) to approximate the true p value or (b) Fisher's exact test for arbitrary tables (again with or without simulation).

Depending on your research question you can also think of pooling the two categories "Medium" and "Higher". Problems with chi-squared approximation will be smaller since expected cell sizes are higher under the null hypothesis of no association.

Note that there is no good "official" rule when the classic chi-squared test performs unacceptably bad. So your statement "the test cannot be applied here" sounds slightly too restrictive. Compare its results with the one obtained from methods (a) and (b) to get a feeling how good/bad the chi-squared test performs in your concrete example.

Here is some R output:

```
tab <- as.table(cbind(c(23, 71, 4), c(3, 3, 0)))

set.seed(10)
chisq.test(tab) # p-value = 0.3267
chisq.test(tab, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 1e6) # p-value = 0.4767
fisher.test(tab) # p-value = 0.3554
fisher.test(tab, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 1e6) # p-value = 0.3553
```

Although the p values differ, you will end up with the same test decision. At least for usual significance levels.

Comment: * SPSS says that 4 cells (66.7%) have expected count less than 5. The minimum expected count is .23.                       I have several problems which can not be merged as you said above(Higher and medium case).

Comment: * can we use 3*2 ,4*2 or other contingency table for fisher test?

Comment: Yes, but you loose the relation to odds ratios and the possibility to test one-sided hypotheses. It is based on a generalisation of the hypergeometric distribution.